# When are user-defined conversion sequences not considered for selecting viable constructors in C++?

Tags: c++, standards, implicit-conversion

I saw the following words in the C++ standard draft N4582:

> [over.best.ics/4] However, if the target is
>
> (4.1) the first parameter of a constructor or
>
> (4.2) the implicit object parameter of a user-defined conversion function
>
> and the constructor or user-defined conversion function is a candidate by
>
> (4.3) 13.3.1.3, **when the argument is the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization**, or
>
> (4.4) 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5, or 13.3.1.6 (in all cases),
>
> user-defined conversion sequences are not considered.

I am confused about the bold part, and don't know how to understand it. I write the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
struct A {
    A(int) {}
    operator int() {cout << "user-defined conversion" << endl; return 0;}
    A(A&) {} //prevent default copy
};
int main()
{
    A a = A(0);
}
```

It works well in g++ 5.3.0, and output "user-defined conversion", which means a user-defined conversion occurs. Certainly, it can be interpreted as that the temporary A(0) is not a consequence of **copy-initialization**. Next I change the program to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
struct A {
    A(int) {}
    operator int() {cout << "user-defined conversion" << endl; return 0;}
    A(A&) {} //prevent default copy
};
A foo() {return A(0);}
int main()
{
    A a = foo();
}
```

Now the value of foo() is a temporary copy-initialized from A(0), but the program still works. Why would this happen?

Comment: Your quote is incorrect; you've omitted 4.2 and renumbered 4.3 to 4.2.

Comment: Do you understand what the "second step" is referring to?

Comment: @ecatmur Sorry for that incorrect quote.

Comment: @T.C. No, I don't really understand the meaning of "second step".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go read [[dcl.init]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17) for the actual standardese. The "second step" here is referring to copy-initializing a variable of class type `A` from something `b` of an unrelated type. In such a case, copy-initialization happens in two steps:

- Step 1: you implicitly convert `b` to `A`. If you call a converting constructor for this, it creates a temporary `A`.
- Step 2: you then initialize the `A` variable from the result of the conversion. (In sane classes, this is typically elided.)

What that quote is saying is that you don't do user-defined conversions in this second step.

For example, with your `A`,  `A a = 0;`. In the first step, you make an `A` temporary from `0`. In the second step, you try to initialize `a` with that temporary - without using user-defined conversions. That fails, because neither `A` constructor is viable.

Comment: And the rationale for not doing user-defined conversions in the second step is that you don't do two user-defined conversions in a single conversion sequence.

Comment: @MSalters So why explicitly forbid it, if it wouldn't work anyway?

Comment: @Barry: It could definitely work; it's just that the compiler needs _some_ limit. Currently the compiler can give up if a single UDC is insufficient. If you set the limit to 2, it needs to check all possible pairs. If you set the the limit to 3, the compiler must check all triplets. The complexity is clearly exponential in the number of allowed UDC's in a single sequence. And keep in mind a specific UDC may be templated and thus require instantiation, so even that single level of checks already is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

There is only 2 ctors, one that take a reference to an existing object (no temporary) and one that takes an int.

Your code produces (with additional messages):

```
int ctor
user-defined conversion
int ctor
user-defined conversion
int ctor
```

The first is the construction inside `foo`.

The second is due to the fact that the returned value can't be constructed by copy as you prevented it, so the compiler convert the value constructed to an `int`.

The third is because it uses the ctor that takes an `int` to build the returned value.

The fourth is (as the second) due to the fact that the returned value can't be used to construct `a`, so it convert it to an `int`.

The fifth is because it then uses the ctor that takes an `int`to build `a`.